# Need to identify an administrator with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo, dao

I do a project of an classified advertisements website, with PHP, Twig, SQL and PDO.

I want to put an elseif in the main.php (last part of code) during the users identification, and check if the user is an admin or not. My Admins value is a boolean in my table. I don't know how to do this checking.

*First my user class :*

```
<?php

class Utilisateur
{
    private $ID_UTILISATEUR;

    private $MDP_UTILISATEUR;

    private $MAIL_UTILISATEUR;

    private $NOM_UTILISATEUR;

    private $PRENOM_UTILISATEUR;

    private $ADMINS;

//CONSTRUCTEUR

    public function __construct($id_user = -1, $user_pass = null, string $user_mail = null, string $nom = null, string $prenom = null, $admins = null)
    {
        $this->ID_UTILISATEUR = $id_user;
        $this->MDP_UTILISATEUR = $user_pass;
        $this->MAIL_UTILISATEUR = $user_mail;
        $this->NOM_UTILISATEUR = $nom;
        $this->PRENOM_UTILISATEUR = $prenom;
        $this->ADMINS = $admins;
    }

//GETTERS

    public function getID_UTILISATEUR()
    {
        return $this->ID_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function getMDP_UTILISATEUR()
    {
        return $this->MDP_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function getMAIL_UTILISATEUR()
    {
        return $this->MAIL_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function getNOM_UTILISATEUR()
    {
        return $this->NOM_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function getPRENOM_UTILISATEUR()
    {
        return $this->PRENOM_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function getADMINS()
    {
        return $this->ADMINS;
    }

//SETTERS

    public function setID_UTILISATEUR($ID_UTILISATEUR)
    {
        $this->ID_UTILISATEUR = $ID_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function setMDP_UTILISATEUR($MDP_UTILISATEUR)
    {
        $this->MDP_UTILISATEUR = $MDP_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function setMAIL_UTILISATEUR($MAIL_UTILISATEUR)
    {
        $this->MAIL_UTILISATEUR = $MAIL_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function setNOM_UTILISATEUR($NOM_UTILISATEUR)
    {
        $this->NOM_UTILISATEUR = $NOM_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function setPRENOM_UTILISATEUR($PRENOM_UTILISATEUR)
    {
        $this->PRENOM_UTILISATEUR = $PRENOM_UTILISATEUR;
    }

    public function setADMINS($ADMINS)
    {
        $this->ADMINS = $ADMINS;
    }

//FONCTION stringID

    public function stringID()
    {
        return "[" . $this->ID_UTILISATEUR . "]";
    }

//FONCTION __toString

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->ID_UTILISATEUR . ", " . $this->NOM_UTILISATEUR . ", " . $this->MAIL_UTILISATEUR;
    }
}
```

*Then my DAO for getting the data of a user :*

```
public function identifier(Utilisateur $u)
{
    try 
    {
        $n = $u->getMAIL_UTILISATEUR();
        $p = $u->getMDP_UTILISATEUR();
        $requete = $this->cnx->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILISATEUR, MDP_UTILISATEUR, MAIL_UTILISATEUR, ADMINS FROM utilisateur WHERE MAIL_UTILISATEUR=:mail and MDP_UTILISATEUR=SHA2(:pass,224)");
        $requete->bindParam(':mail', $n);
        $requete->bindParam(':pass', $p);
        $requete->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Utilisateur');
        // exécution et récupération des résultats
        $data2 = $requete->execute();
        $data2 = $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS|PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Utilisateur');

        return $data2;            
    } 

    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        throw new BDDException ("Impossible d'identifier les données", 201);
    }
}
```

*and the main.php function identify users :*

```
function identifierUtilisateur()
{
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/DAO/MySQLUtilisateurDAO.php";
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . "/views/VueLogin.php";

    $login = new MySQLUtilisateurDAO();
    $login1 = new Utilisateur("", $_POST['mdp'], $_POST['mail'], "", "", "");
    $l = $login->identifier($login1);
        if (empty($l)) {
        echo 'utilisateur non identifié';
        $url = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
        echo ('<a href=' . $url . '>return</a>');
    } 

    else {
$_SESSION['identification'] = $l;
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $mdp = $_POST['mdp'];
        setcookie("MAIL_UTILISATEUR", $mail, time() + 864000, '/'); // expire après 10 jours
        setcookie("MDP_UTILISATEUR", $mdp, time() + 864000, '/');
        $url = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
        afficherAnnoncesUtilisateur();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's not working? To test if someone is an admin u'd do `$user->getADMINS()` with your current code.

Comment: Some pointers, please don't use all-caps for your properties. It's really hurt to the eyes. Also using `SHA2` to store passwords is not recommended. Please have a look at [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: of course, i m not wakeup, and also didnt do my homework since 4 days so I lose some knowledge :p the things i know idsappear in few days if I not work on it.

Comment: `identifier` returns an instance of `Utilisateur` so you can't use it like an array. As you registering your user into the session you could use `if ($_SESSION['identification']->getADMINS()) echo 'Is an admin';`

Comment: @Darkbee tk ^_^